# Page keeps loading when using gulp browser-sync in Docker environment

Tags: docker, gulp, browser-sync

I have set up a Docker environment for my Drupal installation, I created a theme and I want it to work with gulp and browser-sync. When I run my gulp script with browser-sync that is shown below it opens a new browser tab but the page just keeps loading.

My Docker file:

```
version: "2"

services:
  mariadb:
    image: wodby/mariadb:$MARIADB_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_mariadb"
    stop_grace_period: 30s
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $DB_NAME
      MYSQL_USER: $DB_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD

  php:
    image: wodby/drupal-php:$PHP_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_php"
    environment:
      PHP_SENDMAIL_PATH: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -S mailhog:1025
      DB_HOST: $DB_HOST
      DB_USER: $DB_USER
      DB_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
      DB_NAME: $DB_NAME
      DB_DRIVER: $DB_DRIVER
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html

  nginx:
    image: wodby/nginx:$NGINX_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx"
    depends_on:
      - php
    environment:
      NGINX_STATIC_OPEN_FILE_CACHE: "off"
      NGINX_ERROR_LOG_LEVEL: debug
      NGINX_BACKEND_HOST: php
      NGINX_SERVER_ROOT: /var/www/html/web
      NGINX_VHOST_PRESET: $NGINX_VHOST_PRESET
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=nginx'
      - 'traefik.port=80'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${PROJECT_BASE_URL}'

  pma:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_pma"
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: $DB_HOST
      PMA_USER: $DB_USER
      PMA_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
      PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE: 1G
      PHP_MAX_INPUT_VARS: 1G
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=pma'
      - 'traefik.port=80'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:pma.${PROJECT_BASE_URL}'

  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_portainer"
    command: --no-auth -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=portainer'
      - 'traefik.port=9000'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:portainer.${PROJECT_BASE_URL}'

  traefik:
    image: traefik
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_traefik"
    command: -c /dev/null --web --docker --logLevel=INFO
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

My gulpfile:
(I'm not using that environmental variable, but it is to show what url I used there.)

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: "${PROJECT_BASE_URL}"
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your frontend is running on the nginx-container or php-container.

Try to use:

```
...
    proxy: "http://nginx"
... 

or

...
    proxy: "http://php"
...
```

I think you should at least be able to see your browser-sync at your configurated localhost with the right port.

Maybe it does help but I am not sure either.